# だ　and か, Can they be used together?

Tags: grammar

One of my textbook says:
だ　and 　か can not be used together, like:

Example: これは本か。(Is this a book?)

You can NOT say: これは本だか。

The textbook also says:

疑問詞（ぎもんし）（どれ、どちら、どなた、どこ、だれ、いつ etc) When used in a sentence with か, you should not use だ.

Another example: 
どの人が李先生か知っていますか。

You can NOT say: どの人が李先生だか知っていますか。

However, when I surf the Japanese websites, I noticed sentences like this:

この人だれ**だ**か分かりますか？ Here, だ　and 　か is used together.

Isn't it supposed to be この人だれか分かりますか？

Does that mean the textbook is not accurate?

Comment: か is used with 〜のだ as well. 「何の話をしてるんだか。」「まだ二十歳そこらで何をいってるんだか…」「いいんだか悪いんだか」[(ISBN-13: 978-4167476410)](http://www.openisbn.com/isbn/416747641X/)

Answer (score 9):

You can write だか in an embedded clause (usually containing a question word such as どの or だれ) which is a complement of a verb such as 分かる. In a main clause, you must omit だ before か.

So I think you **can** say:

> どの人が李先生だか知っていますか？

Comment: What is a matrix clause? I understand based on context, but I've never heard the term.

Comment: @rintaun It's a synonym for _main clause_ (or _independent clause_) as opposed to _subordinate clause_ (or _dependent clause_, or indeed _embedded clause_).

Comment: This is the only answer that gives the actual rule for when this is allowed. Other answers are misleading because they make it sound like it's always allowed.

Comment: I would say that strictly grammatically it probably -could- be allowed everywhere, but common usage has restricted it to subordinate clauses. My reasoning for this is that だか is of course short for であるか, and であるか is valid anywhere. I would say this restriction is similar to how だ accepts -some- particles that require 連体形, but not all - the others requiring なの.

Comment: @KafkaFuura Your reasoning is not correct, though.  であるか and だか don't have the same distribution, even though the latter is a contracted form of the former.

Comment: @snailboat I meant more that they came from the same source than that they were the same. The reason they don't have the same distribution is because of course they have been used more commonly in this or that situation and so have diverged a bit.

Comment: @KafkaFuura I would say instead that there are grammatical distinctions between the two.  See [this paper](http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2261/54889/1/lr027003.pdf) for some discussion of である vs だ.

Comment: @snailboat The syntactic distinctions the result of their divergence. :) - Just like you can't substitute really substitute 勝った for 勝ちてあり/勝ちてある - Also how だろう／でしょう became an inexplicable monster full of exceptions to make up for the lack of clarity in using just ～う.

Comment: @snailboat It really was an unnecessary comment in the first place because it's really all just speculation and what-ifs. すいません。

Comment: @Earthliŋ Actually, those two terms are not synonymous. A matrix clause is a clause with at least one embedded clause but it doesn't have to be a main clause, and vice versa, a main clause doesn't have to be a matrix clause either. I think here it is better to use "main clause" as opposed to "matrix clause", because 「本当だか*」if standalone is a main clause but not a matrix clause and is ungrammatical with「だか」. Please see [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/matrix-clause-grammar-1691371) and [this Linguistics SE Q&A](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38201).

Comment: @EddieKal Yes, thank you for the edit and comment, that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @snailplane Welcome back!

Answer (score 7):

You can use だ and か together. I think だか is short for であるか. For native speakers, であるか sounds like a formal speech. So we often use だか.

For example, of course you can say

> どの人が李先生か知っていますか。

but you can also say

> どの人が李先生だか知っていますか。

so your textbook is wrong, and

> どの人が李先生であるか知っていますか。

is also Okay, but this is a little bit formal. (maybe young people don't say so.)

Another example, you can say both of

> この人だれか分かりますか？
>
> この人だれだか分かりますか？

There's no difference between them. However

> この人だれであるか分かりますか？

is strange. Because in the latter part, it uses であるか so this sentence should be formal, but in the former, は or が is omitted. So

> この人がだれであるか分かりますか？
>
> この人はだれであるか分かりますか？

is Okay, but I don't usually say so to my friends.

Now, turn back to the main topic. As far as I have mentioned, it seems there is no difference between だ and だか, but unfortunately **it is not true**. Actually, you can say

> これは本か。

but you cannot say

> これは本だか。

This is difficult to explain, but probably because many people feel a sentence doesn't end by だか. Actually, if I heard the latter, I would think "What is Hondaka?". To sum up, these are basically the same but don't end a sentence with だか.

Answer (score 4):

だか is used with question words all the time by us native speakers.  However, you need to know that it is used almost exclusively in informal speech as the more formal forms are であるか and であるのか.

Examples: (Note that I will make the sentences informal on purpose so that だか fits in naturally.)

「何が何だかさっぱりわかんねえ。」= "Dunno what the heck's going on."

「これ、どこのワインだかわかる？」= "Can you tell where this wine comes from?"

「なぜだか教えてくれ！」= "Do tell me why!"

Comment: Can you say : これは本だかどうか知りません。This sentences sound strange. Is it correct?

Comment: @JamesKing これが本かどうか知りません would sound better.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are learning and still in the relatively early stages in which case your text book is introducing you to new grammar step by step.

If you look a few chapters ahead you will probably be introduced to more complex sentences such as:

> いくつあるか知りません |
>   I don't know how many there are.
>
> いくらだか知りません |
>   I don't know how much it is.
>
> だれだったか忘れました。|
>   I forgot who it was.

These came up in chapter 26 of one my first text books (p338 of an Introduction to Modern Japanese, which is quite old).

As you can see from the other answers, these are first steps to more complex uses.

I would suggest you take it step by step (but at a pace you feel comfortable with!). As you come across new more complex but useful  phrases that you can remember, learn them as set-phrases.  You probably know a few already (どういたしまして？）. When you get to study the grammar in your studies, it will be a bit easier because you will have passively built up a feel for it.  It is quite easy to study lots of new grammatical rules and feel you understand them but harder to adopt them all at once (or at least that was my experience).