# Meaning of か in ーだかわからない

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles, particle-か

I found this sentence:

```
その晩、夢を見た。いつの事だかわからない。けれども覚えのある光景があった
```

What is the meaning of that か in 「事だかわからない」？ Is it there to add a "uncertainty" nuance? or is it something else?

Comment: Related: [だ　and か, Can they be used together?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13467/43676)

Answer (score 2):

This か is a question marker, and いつの事だか is an embedded question.

- [Usage of か after a clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010)

As the above link says, it's okay to have だ before か in embedded questions, and the が between the noun and わかる is usually dropped.

- いつのこと(だ)?: "When was it?" (an ordinary question)
- いつのことだ**か**: "when it was" (an embedded question, now a noun clause)
- いつのことだかわからない: "I don't know when it was"

> その晩、夢を見た。いつの事だかわからない。けれども覚えのある光景があった。
> I saw a dream that night. I don't remember when I saw it, but there was a scenery I do remember.