# 「ちょっといいだか」と言う表現は茨城弁？

Tags: grammar, particles, dialects, sentence-final-particles, particle-か

> ビーデルさん、ちょっといいだか？([source](https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=2201727))

> 少将、ちょっといいだか？([source](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354055169358618/episodes/16816452219323096527))

> と、ずっと横で聞いていたシャンロウが手を挙あげて、「ちょっといいだか？」と発言を求めた。([source](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n2773fb/789/))

> 「ちょっといいだか?」「なんです?」ウドリガが出ていこうとした職員を呼び止める。([source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%E7%AB%9C%E6%AE%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E9%81%8E%E3%81%94%E3%81%99%E6%97%A5%E3%80%85_%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%91/d29iDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%22&pg=PT100&printsec=frontcover))

This seems to contradict what we know about だか: [never in a main clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13468/30454). On the other hand, all of these utterances appear to be from people/fictional characters who speak [茨城弁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8C%A8%E5%9F%8E%E5%BC%81). However, I haven't found this recorded as a 茨城弁 feature in Wiki articles or elsewhere. So is it 茨城弁?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely dialectal, but according to [this page](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B), it's not specific to 茨城. To me, this type of sentence-end だか is stereotypical [いなか言葉](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23691/5010) that is associated with no particular region in Japan. (That is not to say だか is an imaginary thing.)

Comment: If I remember correctly, [Seamus and Maggy Mcfly](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Seamus_McFly) was speaking like ～だか in a dubbed version.

Comment: Is だか just だ + か?

Comment: By the way, do you know Frederica from the anime *86 - Eighty-Six*? The 全国共通いなか言葉 examples given in the answer you linked remind me of how she speaks, so I was wondering if she is speaking that imaginary dialect (not sure if this deserve a separated question).

Comment: @Mauro Yes, だ + か. I don't know that anime, but judging from [this page](https://newstisiki.com/archives/63538), she's speaking not in いなか言葉 but in stereotypical "wise old man's speech" (aka のじゃ口調). A character like this is categorized as [のじゃロリ](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA).